# Emoji search not working on Windows 10 upon keyboard language input change

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, language, emoji-keyboard

I'm currently on Windows OS build 19045.3693 and I'm trying to search my emoji like so:
[image: us keyboard emoji search]

As you can see in the image above, it seems to work fine when I set my keyboard language to English US. But, as you can see here:

[image: emoji search attempt with jp keyboard]

When I set my keyboard language to Japanese, I can't even type anything upon opening the panel with `Win+.` to search for an emoji.

Is this a bug and are there any fixes for this?